# How to delete a directory

Tags: windows

I know I can create a directory with `md`.
I don't know how to delete it.
I have tried `del` and `deldir`; they don't work.
I have run `md /?` and `help md` and read the output;
they don't say anything relevant.

How can I delete a directory?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490990(v=technet.10)

Comment: A simple `help` will get you a not too long list of commands, and `help|find /i "dir"` will shorten this to all commands relating to dirs.

Comment: @Biswapriyo - I would normally agree, except this question, has not actually been asked before.  Out of hundreds of thousands of question I couldn't find an obvious duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramhound answered the question, but I'd like to add to that by mentioning two parameters that I always use when removing a directory.

```
rd /s
```

Tells remove directory to also remove all sub-directories.  Without this parameter it will only work without interaction if the directory you are removing has no sub-directories.

```
rd /s/q
```

Tells remove directory to remove all sub-directories even if they are not empty, instead of giving you the warning that one or more sub-directories is not empty.
The "q" means "quiet"

Answer (score 2):

> How can I delete a directory?

You need to use the `rmdir` command to delete a directory within a command prompt.

[Rmdir (rd)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490990(v=technet.10))